# Can I use copy function inide WITH query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

so I have some tables for example here customer and I want to copy csv file contect to the customer table and then add some valeus from other tables with "select ... from"
but I get this error  syntax error at or near "COPY"
it works outside WITH body only

```
WITH new_customer AS (
   COPY customer(name, vat) FROM 'path to csv file'
   DELIMITER ',' 
   CSV HEADER
    RETURNING id, vat
);
```

Comment: That won't work. Use a temporary table, perhaps in a function.

Comment: As to why it won't work: 1) [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html), "Each auxiliary statement in a WITH clause can be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE..." 2) [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) does not have `RETURNING` for its output.